# Error: An Error occurred while preparing the installation, while re-installing Mac OS Sierra

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, install

I am trying to reset my MacBook Pro, and when I was re-installing the macOS I got this error:

> An Error occurred while preparing the installation.  Try running this application again.

When I searched the internet I found most of people met this issue when they just click the `continue` on `Eligibility Verification` window. The reason for this one is because the `date` is error, but I checked my `date` in terminal and it is correct.

I met this error on the `About x minutes remaining` step, and it was wait a few time when this error shown up.

Ps: It said `After 5 minutes remaining` when the installation started, but I wait a long time (half an hour) until the error popped up.

Anyone met this problem and has solution?

Cheers

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! :) Can I ask you to [edit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/297257/edit) your question to clarify how it is you're trying to reset your MBP? For example, are you going into Recovery mode or doing something else? Also, it may be worth you adding the exact details of your MBP.

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the exact same problem and all suggestions to set my date to today do not work. Iam at a loss how to fix this.